# In ASPxGridView from Devexpress, can I specify the colors in color edit column?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm using ASPxGridView from Devexpress and I need color edit column but I need a specific colors in it, not all the colors.
Can I specify which colors I need to show in this color edit column?
If not, which control I have to use to get what I want? any suggestions?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S33198.aspx

ASPxColorEdit doesn't support custom colors.

You could try something like this:
1.Take GridViewDataTextColumn and set its EditItemTemplate to your custom template (must implement System.Web.UI.ITemplate)

2.In your custom template use some other color picker component (farbtastic, jPicker, colorpicker)

3.Use chosen picker component to set GridViewDataTextColumn value in order to save it.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for this, I used special combobox with image support and I made images according to colors I want to use (static but enough for now), thanx any way